# EWMA in python using the arch 3.2 package and pandas

Tags: finance, python, garch

I have a hard time figuring out whether my EWMA calculation of variance is correct when using the python package ARCH 3.2.

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
rm = am.univariate.EWMAVariance(0.94)
am.univariate.ZeroMean(x,volatility=rm).fit(disp='off').conditional_volatility[-1]
```

to obtain the EWMA variance over the dataframe x. I cannot figure out:

- Why I need to fit the volatility model whereas EWMA is parameterless.
- If the ordering of dates is taken care of. Should the time series
  be passed in a given chronological order?